# How to find an upper bound for an asymptotic relation $\frac{\epsilon}{\delta^{2}}$ using that $\delta \ll \epsilon^{2}$?

Tags: asymptotics, epsilon-delta, approximation-theory, perturbation-theory

Assume I have two small parameters $0< \epsilon \ll 1$ and $0< \delta \ll 1$ such that $\delta \gg \epsilon^{2}$. I would like to find an upper bound for the quantity $A = O\left(\frac{\epsilon^{2}}{\delta^{2}}\right) \times O\left(\frac{1}{\epsilon}\right)$, and more precisely I am hoping to find that $A \ll \frac{C}{\epsilon^{2}}$ for some constant $C$.

Now since from above we have 
$A = O\left(\frac{\epsilon}{\delta^{2}}\right)$ and using $\frac{1}{\delta} \ll \frac{1}{\epsilon^{2}}$ twice, we can write

$A = O\left(\frac{\epsilon}{\delta^{2}}\right)  \ll \frac{1}{\epsilon \delta} \ll \frac{1}{\epsilon^{3}}$

so I have bounded $A$ by $\epsilon^{-3}$ - but can I do better and show that if it is true that $A \ll \frac{C}{\epsilon^{2}}$ ?

Comment: So all you know is $\delta \gg \varepsilon^2$? Then you can't do it. For example, you could have $\delta=\varepsilon^{1.75}$ and $A=\frac{\varepsilon}{\delta^2}$, then $A$ is actually $\varepsilon^{-2.5}$.

Comment: Ok, so $\epsilon^{-3}$ is the best one can do? @Ian

Comment: What you basically have is "infinitesimally better" than $O(\epsilon^{-3})$; specifically $A=o(\epsilon^{-3})$ and no better.